# How do you wrap an image around a floated div like a paragraph?

Tags: css, html

I have a floated right `div`, and the `p` tags are wrapping around it correctly, but I was wondering if it's possible to have the image wrap around the floated element as well.

Here is the code:

```html
<section class="entry-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
    <div class="quick-facts">
        <h3>Quick Facts Box</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>There are over 1000 bones in a complete blue whale </li>
            <li>Blue whales live to be very old and have many children</li>
        </ul>
        <img src="/2014/02/IMG_1325-275x275.jpg">
    </div>

    <p>The Noyo Center for Science &amp; Education (Noyo Center) will serve as a cold water marine research center for the community college and State college system while educating the public (residents, school children, visitors) through exhibits, lectures, classes, and guided tours about the impacts that humans have on our marine and terrestrial environment and ways that we can work to improve conservation of these resources. The Noyo Center’s primary goal is to foster activities promoting research and education that support ocean and coastal ecosystem restoration. Secondary goals are to develop education and research that support sustainable forestry and fishing practices, and to increase ocean and ecological literacy. The development program includes the Nature Center and Aquarium (6,100 SF) and Marine Research facilities (3,250 SF).</p>

    <p>In 2010 the Noyo Center design won an award from the Redwood Chapter of the American Institute of Architects (AIA).</p>

    <h2>Noyo Center Property Acquistion Completed!</h2>

    <img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-102" alt="fort-bragg" src="/2014/02/fort-bragg.jpg" width="1000" height="275">

    <p>“Last week, escrow closed on the City’s acquisition of 11½ acres from Georgia Pacific for future development of the Noyo Center for Science &amp; Education. The property is located adjacent to the Noyo Headlands Park property on the southern part of the former mill site (near the City’s wastewater treatment facility). The property was acquired with a “repayable” grant provided by the State Coastal Conservancy.</p>

</section>
```

Comment: You need to give us some css for context, and it would be best to make an example on http://jsfiddle.net/. As a side note, most likely your main issue is that the image is too wide (1000px it appears), as it should normally position next to a floated element.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually wrap anything inside an img tag because it doesn't consist a closing tag like paragraph tag has a closing tag `<p></p>` .

If you want a border image to be shown around the div then you can refer to this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

I think your question is too much confusing because i cant see any paragraph tags wrapping any div in your code .If i got your question wrong then please elaborate or show any example similar to what you want to exactly achieve .